# New templates named JLIB_INSTALLER_DEFAULT_STYLE

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates

Sometimes, when I install a new template in Joomla, the default template style name is set to `JLIB_INSTALLER_DEFAULT_STYLE`. So far I haven't found any particular pattern as to when it happens, but it usually happens on localhost (not always though, and not only on localhost). It also happens with Shape5 templates (Vertex framework), and sometimes with other templates as well.

The file `JOOMLAROOT/language/en-GB/en-GB.lib_joomla.ini` has the following line:

```
JLIB_INSTALLER_DEFAULT_STYLE="%s - Default"
```

But for some reason the string is used, and not the value.

Does anyone know why this happens? Is it a bug in Joomla or in the templates?

Comment: Are you experiencing this on J3.3.6 or an older version?

Comment: Yes, Joomla 3.3.6, but it has happened before on earlier versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this issue with a lot of Joomlart templates and found a few references that helped me, hopefully they will also help you. It seems to be a known issue with A**keeba Backup / Admin Tools** - do you have these installed by any chance?

In the [Official Joomlart Forum](http://www.joomlart.com/forums/showthread.php?95799-Jlib_installer_default_style) one of the admins has suggested the following fix;

Change;

```
/public_html/staging/plugins/system/admintools/admintools/main.php
```

to

```
/public_html/staging/plugins/system/admintools/admintools/main_DISABLE.php
```

I'm not exacyly sure what this is disabling so you may want to be careful and experiment.

Another reference is on the [Official Akeeba Backup Forum](https://www.akeebabackup.com/support/akeeba-backup-3x/20288-jlib-installer-default-style-due-to-admintools.html) where the admin reports;

> If the core Joomla! library translation file for your administrator
>   language does not have the translation for the
>   JLIB_INSTALLER_DEFAULT_STYLE string you will end up seeing the
>   untranslated string. If your administrator is English you should see
>   the correct translation ("Default").

Hope this helps.